# Pandas Series.as_matrix() doesn't properly convert a series of nd arrays into a single nd array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe where one column is labeled "feature_vector" and contains in it a 1d numpy array with a bunch of numbers. Now, I am needing to use this data in an scikit learn model, so I need it as a single numpy array. So naturally I call DataFrame["feature_vector"].as_matrix() to get the numpy array from the correct series. The only problem is, the as_matrix() function will return an 1d numpy array where each element is an 1d numpy array containing each vector. When this is passed to an sklearn model's .fit() function, it throws an error. What I instead need is a 2d numpy array rather than the 1d array of 1d arrays. I wrote this work around, which uses presumably unnecessary memory and computation time:

```
x = dataframe["feature_vector"].as_matrix()
#x is a 1d array of 1d arrays.
l = []
for e in x:
    l.append(e)
x = np.array(l)
#x is now a single 2d array.
```

Is this a bug in pandas .as_matrix()? Is there a better work around that doesn't require me to change the structure of the original dataframe?

Comment: Look at `x.dtypes`.  That column probably is `object`.  So the column cells contain pointers to arrays elsewhere in memory.  `asmatrix` is creating the same thing with `numpy` - an array of pointers to arrays.  Try `np.stack(x)`.  Assuming all those arrays are the same size, that should concatenate them as rows of a new array.

Comment: Stack would be effectively doing the same thing that my workaround is accomplishing, yes? That's much better but still requires an extra function call that I'd like to avoid. Is there anyway the pandas dataframe could return the numpy areay in the 2d format I want it in in the first place? @hpaulj

Comment: Too lazy to type that extra line?  If you think having `pandas` do the job will be more efficient, then you didn't understand my explanation.